# Not able to login to AWS instance using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, port

I created new EC2 instance (Ubuntu). It was working well until yesterday. Then I did a stop and start of the instance from the console. After which I'm not able to ssh using port 22.

Right now I'm not able to check the `fstab` content or `sshconfig` or any config , as I'm not able to login.

From the AWS console , `EC2-> Get Instance Screenshot` I'm able to see below error.

> Failed to start create volatile files and directories.
>   welcome to emergency mode . after logging in type "journalctl -xb" to see system log or systemctl reboot...............

I tried detach and attach volume. it didn't work.
I don't have snapshot of it to restore. my root device and block device are same `/dev/sda1`.
I'm able to login to other instance in the same VPC as the problematic one.
It has the same security group configured. Telnet to other port 80 , 443 works fine. But ssh using port 22 says connection refused. 
It does not have any public IP, usually I use private IP to connect.

I'm not finding way to login from AWS console too.

Comment: It sounds like your operations system has been damaged. Create a new instance, mount the existing volume as a data volume, and migrate the data to a working operating system.